# Error using withErrors() when returning view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-validation, laravel-form

I would like to submit my laravel form, with some errors if my csv is not set to the input file.
So I did like this, simple, basic :

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'csv' => 'required|mimes:csv',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return view(backpack_view('upload/upload-nb-postes'))->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

The validator fails, of course, so it should render my view with error messages but I have an error :

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::getBag()
```

I checked the MessageBag class and ... yes, there is no `getBag()` method.
So what should I do ? I can't use the `withErrors()` method...

I tried with :

```
return view(backpack_view('upload/upload-nb-postes'))->withErrors(['csv' = > 'test');
```

Same problem, I also checked that there is some error messages.

Maybe update with composer ? I won't crash my project.

More information :

```
Laravel version : 6.17.1
Laravel locale : fr
Laravel config cached : false
PHP version : 7.4.3
```

Comment: Try without **error** directive,  `@if($errors->has('csv'))
    Error!!! @endif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `errors` method of $validator instance.

```
return view(backpack_view('upload/upload-nb-postes'))->withErrors($validator->errors());
```

Inside your view, use $errors->first('csv') to access error message.

Comment: I still have the issue, but the problem must coming from my view. I juste wrote the following : `@error('csv') <div class="invalid-feedback">dddddd</div> @enderror `, and when I remove this, I can see my view (of course without the error). Maybe Laravel doesn't use `@error` anymore ?

Comment: I haven't ever used @error component. If you want to use this feature, you have to throw ValidationException instead of passing $errors into view by yourself.